# Large IF Array formula in Vba code

Tags: arrays, vba, formula, worksheet

I am trying to put this array formula in a VBA code but it is giving syntax error. I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
Sub Highestvalue()
    Dim p As Integer
    p = ActiveSheet.WorksheetFunction.FormulaArray = "=LARGE(IF(F:F="apples",G:G),10)"
    MsgBox p
End Sub
```

Comment: Your string is broken, double quotes inside a string to escape them: `=  "=LARGE(IF(F:F=""apples"",G:G),10)"`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have at least 10 "apples" in column F? Otherwise the Large function won't work as the array of results is too small.